# Using Docker to build a Flask and Angular App

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile

I am relatively new to building application with Angular and Flask and I have a problem when trying to build my application with Docker.

My directory structure looks like this:

- frontend (Angular Application)
- backend (Flask Application)

  - /dist (Generated after Angular project is built)
- Dockerfile
- docker-compose.yml

How do I automate this process so that first the *dist* folder gets generated and then my container get built? I don't want to use shell-scripts or anything else. In an ideal world I would be able to run `docker compose up --build` without the need to build the frontend first by hand.
Do you have any solutions? Thanks for helping!

My backend serves the static files located in the *dist* directory. Local development works fine this way. I have already written a Dockerfile for the backend, which also works. It looks like this:

```
FROM python:latest

WORKDIR /backend

COPY backend/dist /backend/dist

COPY backend/requirements.txt /backend

COPY backend/src /backend/src/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "./src/app.py"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your backend image a multistage build. This way you'd generate the required files and then run a smaller image.

Your Dockerfile will look something like this:

```
FROM node AS builder

WORKDIR /app-build
# You can slim the following copy statement to just what you need
COPY . .
RUN ./somethingAngularYouNeed -o ./dist

FROM python:latest

WORKDIR /backend

# The following line copies results from the first stage
COPY --from=builder /app-build/dist /backend/dist

COPY backend/requirements.txt /backend

COPY backend/src /backend/src/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "./src/app.py"]
```